# Not able to add the bot to a channel through microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

While adding the bot to a channel through microsoft graph API, getting the below error

```
    "error": {
        "code": "BadGateway",
        "message": "Failed to execute backend request.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-05-18T09:53:27",
            "request-id": "15a095d5-baa4-4373-9722-97375f13206e",
            "client-request-id": "56717e9c-0fd9-1dbf-a8cf-c172cdc7e0dd"
        }
    }
}
```

we're using this API to make the request

```
POST /teams/teamID/installedApps
Content-type: application/json

{
   "teamsApp@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/teamsAppId"
}
```

Also we have granted all the permissions for this API

Comment: Does your app have RSC permissions? Currently, this operation does not support installation of apps that require resource-specific consent permissions.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT how can we fix it? what is the role of RSC permissions here?

Comment: Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http